# Not a function (mocking error?)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to do some unit testing on my Ionic app, using the Karma-jasmine framework, and it's giving me quite the headache. <strike>I have a function in my controller I want to test by giving it some dummy input (the credentials), but I keep getting the errors</strike>

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$controller')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.credentials.username = "uname"')
```

I've tried some alternate ways to do this, but one of them kept giving me some bogus that I needed to add dependencies from my `services.js` as well (i.e. `$ionicPopup`), which might have some truth to it, but I'm super new to all of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've made a lot of progress by mostly rewriting this, but I'm now getting the error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'LoginService.initiateRequest(
                          $scope.credentials.username,
                          $scope.credentials.password)')
                   at c:/Users/name/git/mobile/www/js/controllers.js:18
```

It's saying that it's not a function in my controllers.js file...which it DEFINITELY is. Really not understanding this one. Is it something to do with services?

I have here my `controllers.tests.js` file...

```
describe('Controllers', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp.services', 'myApp.controllers'));

    var mockRequest = {

    }
    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('initiateRequest', mockRequest);
        });
    });
    var $rootScope, $controller, $sharedProperties, $resource;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope) {
        myScope = $rootScope.$new();
        $scope = {};
        $state = {};
        LoginService = {};
        localStorageService = {};
        sharedProperties = {};
        $ionicLoading = myScope;
        initiateRequest = mockRequest;
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));
    describe('$scope.login()', function() {
        it('does something', function() {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('LoginController', {
                $scope: $scope,
                $state: $state,
                LoginService: LoginService,
                localStorageService: localStorageService,
                sharedProperties: sharedProperties,
                $ionicLoading: $ionicLoading
            });
            expect($scope.login).toBeDefined(true);
            expect($scope.show).toBeDefined(true);
            $scope.login();
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: why is your controller starting with a `.`? should it not be something like app.controller()

Comment: parentheses and braces aren't balanced in `controllers.tests.js`

Comment: @Barmar D'oh! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('Controllers', function () {

  beforeEach(module('myApp.services', 'myApp.controllers'));

  var mockRequest = {};

  beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('initiateRequest', mockRequest);
    });
  });
  var $controller, sharedProperties, state, scope, ionicLoading, LoginService, localStorageService, initiateRequest;
  beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function ($rootScope, _$controller_) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $controller = _$controller_;
      ionicLoading = {};
      sharedProperties = {};
      LoginService = {};
      localStorageService = {};
      initiateRequest = mockRequest;
    });
  });
  describe('$scope.login()', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      $controller('LoginController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $state: state,
        LoginService: LoginService,
        localStorageService: localStorageService,
        sharedProperties: sharedProperties,
        $ionicLoading: ionicLoading
      });
      scope.$apply();
    });
    it('does something', function () {
      expect(scope.login).toBeDefined();
      expect(scope.show).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This mostly works, but still gives me the "undefined is not a function (evaluating...)" issue.